# How do I get this function to work as a reactive shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization

I am trying to convert a function I wrote into a reactive shiny app. However I have very little experience with shiny. I went through the tutorial and tried to adapt my function but have so far not been successful.

The original function creates a density plot of the number of mutations you expect to observe in a stretch of DNA of length y, if you have z number of individuals, and a mutation rate of x.

```
x = 1/1000
y = 100
z = 100
mutation_counter <- function(x,y,z) {
  dist_expect_muts <- replicate(1000, {
    sum(observed_muts <- sample(0:1, (y*z), prob=c(1-x,x), replace = TRUE)>0)
  })
  dist_muts <- as.data.frame(dist_expect_muts)
  ggplot(dist_muts, aes(dist_expect_muts)) + geom_density() + xlab('Number of frameshift/gain of stop codon mutations observed')
}
```

I tried to make this into a shiny app where I can play around with the values of x,y and z to see how it influences the distribution but so far it does not work. I think my code probably has several fundamental mistakes, as I am not yet comfortable with the structure of shiny apps.

Unfortunately I do not see any error messages when I run the app, so it is hard to debug. The sliders seem to work, but no plot is generated.

The ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Mutation probability"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x", "Probability of mutation:", 
                  min=1/10000000, max=1/10, value=1/100),

      sliderInput("y", "Size of region:", 
                  min = 10, max = 1000000, value = 10000, step= 100),

      sliderInput("z", "Number of individuals:", 
                  min = 1, max = 100000, value = 100, step= 100)

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)
```

The server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
function(input, output) {


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    x <- input$x
    y <- input$y
    z <- input$z
    dist_expect_muts <- replicate(1000, {
      sum(observed_muts <- sample(0:1, (y*z), prob=c(1-x,x), replace = TRUE)>0)
    })
    dist_muts <- as.data.frame(dist_expect_muts)


    # draw the density plot
    ggplot(dist_muts, aes(dist_expect_muts)) + geom_density() + xlab('Number of mutations')
  })

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? I see a plot when running this code. The problem just seems to be that your function takes a very long time to run. Your default values are `mutation_counter(1/10,10000,100)`. You can't have very reactive plots if the data take a long time to generate.

Comment: Yes, MrFlick is right. It works a lot better if you change the `replicate(1000` to `replicate(10`. You might want to make that value into an input parameter, and develop a formula for the expected calculation time and display it. Then only do the calculation with an explicit `actionButton`. You can use `eventReactive` for that - it is designed for such a case.

Comment: Ah this must be it, I was running it on a slow computer. Thank you very much!